# Efficiently computing multiple tensor inner products

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy, tensor

I'm working with a `k x k x k x k` tensor (say `S`) and an array `X` of size `(n, k)`. Roughly, `X`'s rows correspond to node features for a graph. For each pair of edges (say `e = (u, v)` and `e' = (u_, v_)`) I want to compute a new element as follows:

```py
elt = np.sum(S * np.multiply.outer(np.outer(X[u, :], X[v, :]), np.outer(X[u_, :], X[v_, :])))
```

I wonder if there is a way to do this more efficiently instead of 4 nested loops over indices.
If I was working with just pairs of nodes and `S` was just a `k x k` matrix, this could be written simply as

```
all_elts = X @ S @ X.T
```

However, I'm not sure how this generalizes over multiple dimensions. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: With `@` the last 2 dimensions perform the `dot` sum-of-products.  The other dimensions are 'batch' ones, subject to the normal `broadcasting` rules.  While not necessarily the fastest, `np.einsum` is handy tool for expressing complicated products.

Comment: For `einsum` think `result_?,?,? = sum(?,?,?) S_i,j,k,l  X_?,? X_?,?`.  Fill in ? indices.

Comment: @hpaulj: Thank you! I had no idea `numpy` implements Einstein notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to show how to use `einsum()`:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

n = 4
x = np.random.randn(n, n)
S = np.random.randn(n, n, n, n)

res = np.zeros((n, n, n, n))
for i, j, k, l in product(range(n), range(n), range(n), range(n)):
    res[i, j, k, l] = np.sum(S * np.multiply.outer(np.outer(x[i, :], x[j, :]), np.outer(x[k, :], x[l, :])))

res2 = np.einsum("efgh,ae,bf,cg,dh->abcd", S, x, x, x, x)
np.allclose(res, res2)
```

Comment: Probably should have kept the `(n, k), k=4` notation just for the sake of giving the warning that large `n` values could lead to memory errors, as you're constructing a `(n,n,n,n)` shaped array.